# Getting List of Elements by XPath in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am attempting to automate my monthly expense report process using Selenium and Python. I can log in and navigate to the list of expenses, dates, and locations. I am having trouble saving them to a list in Python. Currently, I am stuck at saving the dates.

I have the XPath right. When entered into the Chrome console on the page, it brings up every instance of the desired dates. But trying to save them to a variable in Python doesn't seem to be working. When debugging, the "dates" list has a length of 0.

```
time.sleep(4)
dates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//time')
print(dates)
```

This is the HTML:

```
< time datetime="2017-07-11T05:00:00.000Z">07/11/2017</time>
```

I'm trying to get the "07/11/2017" out of every instance of this. Using the "//time" xpath in the Chrome console pulls up a list of 25 elements, which is accurate. I just don't know why the dates list ends up empty. I figure I misunderstand how the find_elements_by_xpath function works. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: how about replacing `sleep` with `WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//time")))`

Comment: Why do you think the list is empty? what happens if you do `print(len(dates))`?

Comment: By the way is the time tag is inside of any frame of iframes?

Comment: @GaurangShah WebDriverWait wasn't working earlier when I was trying to press a button (the specific button object is odd with this website). Using base driver was the only way I could get it to work.

Comment: @Guy It returns 0. I found that earlier by using the debug function in my IDE

Comment: Are the dates inside an `<ifarme>` tag? or in another tab/window?

Comment: @Guy no. it's always in the current window, and not in an iframe

Answer (score -1):

Hope it helps you. Let me know if you need further assistance. Choose which ever option you thing will serve the purpose.

Option 1:

```
time.sleep(4)
dates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//time')
for date in dates:
    print(date.text)
```

Option 2:

```
time.sleep(4)
dates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//time')
print(dates.get_attribute('datatime'))
for date in dates:
    print(date.text)
```

Comment: in both of your example `dates` is list so it can't have `text` or  `get_attribute` functions.